# VBA COUNTIF with Custom Date Formats

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I need help counting the number of cells with a specified year in an Excel range. The code I am currently using is as follows:

```vb
yrRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary Tab").Range("A8:AE8")
yr = 2023
CountMonths = Application.Evaluate("SUM(IF(YEAR(yrRange)=yr,1,0))")
```

However, this code returns 0 even if a date like Jul-23 (displayed as 01/07/2023 in "dd/mm/yyyy" format) is within the specified range.

Here is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MQkF.png) of the custom date format I am using.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `yr` in the formula with the literal `2023`, and same with the `yrRange` literal of `A8:AE8`?

Comment: You can't use `yrRange` and `yr` like that inside `Evaluate`.

Comment: `CountMonths = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(IF(YEAR(" & yrRange & ")=" & yr & ",1,0))")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to improve the code with "Application.Evaluate", but this code works for me:

```
Dim CountMonths As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim yr As String
yr = "2023"
CountMonths = 0
For j = 8 To Range("AE8").Column
    If Year(CDate(Cells(8, j))) = yr Then
        CountMonths = CountMonths + 1
    End If
Next j
Debug.Print CountMonths
```